# Setting SSH for windows Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, git

I am following the [thread to set up SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

But I get below error on 5th step

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Below is the detailed log

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa 
SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Kiran B/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: how did you create the key? Where did you place it? Did you add it to your account on github?

Comment: Created the key using the instructions in the link. Its placed inside C:\Users\Kiran B\.ssh. Yes I added

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a SSH config file

#### How to add ssh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced same issue.

Maybe your **ssh identities** was deleted.
If run this command

> ssh-add -l

You get this message "**The agent has no identities.**"

---

I recommended you, generate a new `ssh` key

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your github mail account"

- [Press enter]
- [Type a secure passphrase]
- Enter same passphrase again

You get identification saved message.

Now, run this command,

> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Enter your passphrase.

---

Copy your SSH RSA Key by

> clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Now,
Goto your GitHub account > Settings > SSH Keys > New SSH Key and Paste the copied key.

Verify SSH connection with GitHub.

> ssh -T git@github.com

Finally, you get this message,

Hi ...! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.